# code for ODBC Mingw with wxwidget getten error

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I found this code use sql.h and sqlext ;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

using namespace std;

void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle){
    SQLCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLCHAR message[1024];
    if(SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        cout<<"Message: "<<message<<"\nSQLSTATE: "<<sqlstate<<endl;
}

int main(){

    SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle;
    SQLRETURN retcode;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    SQLCHAR retconstring[1024];
    switch(SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle,
                NULL,
                (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=d:\\d\\oooo.mdb",
                SQL_NTS,
                retconstring,
                1024,
                NULL,
                SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)){
        case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
            break;
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        case SQL_ERROR:
            show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
            goto FINISHED;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLCHAR*)"select * from testtable", SQL_NTS)){
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
        goto FINISHED;
    }
    else{
        char name[64];
        char address[64];
        int id;
        while(SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle)==SQL_SUCCESS){
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, name, 64, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, address, 64, NULL);
            cout<<id<<" "<<name<<" "<<address<<endl;
        }
    }

FINISHED:
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle );
    SQLDisconnect(sqlconnectionhandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);

}
```

and when to use it over gui wxwidget codeblocks the SQLCHAR refused and compiler say must convert to SQLWCHAR , I change it and run with no error
but after run whene program try to connect odbc is getting error message :
    Datasource name not found SQLstate:IM002

note:
project use UTF-8 formatt

can any one identify the problem??

Comment: You are not exactly using wxWidgets in your code snippet, are you?

Comment: here is just only original code not that modified by wxwidgets, i used same code from console example above in gui wxwidgets frame project and replace cout with wxMessagebox